# Error with \Chapter? Two table of contents formed with standard command

Tags: table-of-contents

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\title{ 
\normalfont\normalsize
\textsc{Location}\\ % Your university, school and/or department name(s)
\vspace{25pt} % Whitespace
\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\ % Thin top horizontal rule
\vspace{20pt} % Whitespace
{\huge Idea: 1}\\ % The assignment title
\vspace{12pt} % Whitespace
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\\ % Thick bottom horizontal rule
\vspace{12pt} % Whitespace
}

\author{\LARGE J} % Your name

\date{\normalsize\today} % Today's date (\today) or a custom date
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Something}
\end{document}
```

This creates the standard contents page expected, but also on the next page it creates an additional one with erratic word and page numbering.
This doesn't occur when \chapter is removed.

Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Your example is missing \begin{document}. But beside this the output is normal, on page 4 is the normal header of empty pages (but it could be changed to plain style or empty).

Comment: So to remove this you would use \pagestyle{plain}?

Comment: this will change the page style of all pages, to change only the  empty page between chapters I would redefine \cleardoublepage (or better use a class like scrbook which has options for it).

Comment: @https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer Or `memoir`